# multiple fixtures on one site

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, fixtures

Hello I'm creating a basic sample application from emberjs guide. The todos app. I want to create a small modification and create two seperate lists of things todo. I also want to work on static data. I have one fixtures collection, I would like to add second list and iterate and display it seperatly

How can I do this ? I can't find any info about this.

Answer (score 0):

A second list of the same data type?  If so you'd want a level above the todos, like a todo owner, and you'd want to grab that owner, then grab his todos.  If you are just talking about a second fixture data on a different data type, the Todos.Owner.FIXTURES shows that as well.

```
Todos.Owner = DS.Model.extend({
  todos: hasMany('todo')
});


Todos.Todo = DS.Model.extend({
  owner: belongsTo('owner'),
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  isCompleted: DS.attr('boolean')
 });

 Todos.Owner.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    todos: [1],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    todos: [2,3],
  },   
];

Todos.Todo.FIXTURES = [
{
  id: 1,
  owner: 1,
  title: 'Learn Ember.js',
  isCompleted: true
},
{
  id: 2,
  owner: 2,
  title: '...',
  isCompleted: false
},
{
  id: 3,
  owner: 2,
  title: 'Profit!',
  isCompleted: false
}
];
```

Comment: As I wrote I want second list of todo things so I want the same data type. I want to collections of Todo items not a second collection of diffrent object

Comment: Then what I wrote is your best bet, you can't switch out the fixtures data.  You could clear the store and push additional data after the fact, or you could call store.filter for specific items in the fixtures.